# Blender 4.0 - Move Keyframe Precision?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

In Blender 3.6 I used to be able to precision move keyframes by holding the CTRL key while moving them. This doesn't seem to be the case in 4.0.

How do I do this in 4.0?

Comment: Don't know about your Blender, but in my 3.6.5 I do this with the `Shift` key like in all previous versions. And it works in my Blender 4.0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Open Status bar to review that hotkeys are suggested by Blender:

[image]

If you are not happy this the key, you can change it in *Transform modal map* in user settings:

[image]

Comment: That's weird. It's telling me its shift and yet nothing happens when I hold it.

Comment: Check keymap, maybe something is overriding shift

Comment: I've tried that and even changing the hotkey to something else and it doesn't seem to work. It's weird cause 3.6 it works just fine and I imported my settings of it when I installed 4.0 so it should work too.